# Prevent users accessing Firefox menu items

Tags: firefox, gpo

Have a locked down closed system where firefox is used in a couple of instances to display help files some applications use.
We've found that users can use the "File" menu to either bring up a "Save-as" or "Open" dialog.
From there they can do "Ctrl-N" and bring up a file explorer window and from there start doing naughty things.  Run powershell, etc.

I have used GPO to set 'Display Menu Bar" to "Never" and this stop users right clicking and displaying the menu bar.  However they can still do "Alt-F" which then opens the menu and they can do the actions mentioned above.
Is there *any* way to prevent them from using "Alt-F"?

I have a .cfg file and Ive added these lines to it:
lockPref("ui.key.menuAccessKeyFocuses", false)
lockPref("ui.key.menuAccessKey", 0)

but made no difference.  Users can still access File menu.

So any method, GPO, css, that will stop this needed.

Thanks